# Inserción de carácter inesperado en JSON tras codificar consulta mysql con php

Tags: php, mysql, api

Quiero montar una API con php la cual me devuelva los resultados de una consulta a mi base de datos tras pasarle unas fechas por método get, todo esto lo ejecuto correctamente, el problema es que al codificar el resultado de la consulta a JSON para consumirla, esto me inserta un caracter inesperado al inicio de cada dimensión del array de la consulta: "0" y lo sigue el campo fecha junto con la repetición de la fecha nuevamente el primero sin el indentificador de columna, de donde viene esto y como puedo eliminarlo? Gracias

Así genero el JSON tras recibir los parámetros por get

```
$query ="SELECT date, pm1, pm25, pm4, pm10 FROM particulas WHERE date BETWEEN '$date1' and '$date2'";
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
     
      
    mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8"); 
      

    
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){

    $rawdata = array(); 


    $i=0;

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $rawdata[$i] = $row;
        $i++;
    }

    
}

    if (empty($rawdata)) {
      
    echo "No hay datos de esas fechas";
        } else {
    echo json_encode($rawdata); 
        }
    
    mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Y esta es la respuesta que obtengo con los ceros comentados

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y si por el contrario genero la respuesta con una consulta select * recibo este 0 seguido del id repetido dos veces, seguido de la fecha nuevamente repetida dos veces, ¿de donde viene esto y como puedo corregirlo? Gracias.

```
$query ="SELECT * FROM particulas WHERE date BETWEEN '$date1' and '$date2'";
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estas son las columnas de la base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día, está obteniendo el array de ambas formas. Con el número de campo y el nombre de campo.
Pruebe cambiar la línea

```
//while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $rawdata[$i] = $row;
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Gracias, se solucionó con MYQLI_ASSOC

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu problema viene porque utilizas un campo llamado "date". Pero ese nombre de campo es una palabra reservada de mysql:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html

si buscas, veras que hay una funcion llamada Date, y en las palabras reservadas aparece tambien. Es muy posible que al hacer la consulta, interprete tu campo como funcion y al no ser correcto, te este devolviendo ese 0.

Te recomendaria que cambies ese nombre de campo, por otro mas acorde a la tabla. algo "particulas_date" o lo que mejor te sugiera.